# How do I add collision in 2d JS/HTML game?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For school I have to make a browser game, however I have near zero knowledge of JS and if I ask any questions my teacher just says I have to google it. I just copied a bunch of the W3Schools game code and edited it but I'm now trying to figure out how to add collision, so I went to Google and tried searching for collision detection but everything I could find was stuff I don't understand yet. So I asked again if he could help me, this time he tried but he used words he hasn't explained in class yet so I was still stuck.

Now I'm here, asking you to help me with my code. I'm trying to recreate Mario Party 2 Hexagon Heat with pillars and what I basically need is collision on the bottom of the player and the top of object so the player(s) can stand on them. I also want to add an animation when you press F11, the pillars rise from the lava and the player spawns in when the animation is finished. Next to those things I need an ending screen but if I have the collision + animation I should be able to figure that out.

I'm kind of desperate because I have to turn my work in next week. It is for a grade so I really hope somone is willing to help me.

```js
window.addEventListener("keyup", ev => {
  if (ev.keyCode === 122) {
    document.getElementById("startScreen").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
    startGame()
  }
});

var myGamePiece;
var lava;
var pillarOne;
var pillarTwo;
var pillarThree;
var pillarFour;
var pillarFive;
var bgMusic;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, ("../img/player.png"), 765, 315, "image");
    pillarOne = new component(120,500, "#FEF355", 300, 345);
    pillarTwo = new component(120,500, "#68B8F0", 510, 345);
    pillarThree = new component(120,500, "#FD4320", 720, 345);
    pillarFour = new component(120,500, "#FC528F", 930, 345);
    pillarFive = new component(120,500, "#55D05A", 1140, 345);
    lava = new component(2000, -80, "#FE7D23", 0, 900);
    bgMusic = new sound("music/bgmusic.mp3");
    bgMusic.play();
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    clear : function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
  stop : function() {
    location.reload();
  }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.gamearea = myGameArea;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.gravity = 0.1;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;{
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
         }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY +  this.gravitySpeed;
    }
}

function sound(src) {
    this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
    this.sound.src = src;
    this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
    this.sound.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    this.play = function(){
        this.sound.play();
    }
}

function stopGame() {
       if (myGamePiece.y >= 850) {
           myGameArea.stop();
       }
     }

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    stopGame()
    pillarOne.update();
    pillarTwo.update();
    pillarThree.update();
    pillarFour.update();
    pillarFive.update();
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speedY = -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speedY = 1; }
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
    lava.update();
  }

  function everyinterval(n) {
      if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
      return false;
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}

html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #303030;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 240%;
}

p {
  font-size: 130%;
}

canvas {
    background-color: #303030;
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#lineStart{
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #A5A5A5, 0 0 2px #A5A5A5, 0 0 3px #A5A5A5, 0 0 4px #A5A5A5, 0 0 5px #A5A5A5, 0 0 6px #A5A5A5, 0 0 7px #A5A5A5;
}

#startScreen{
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;         /* When the spec is finished */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  100%   {left: -50%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  100%   {left: -50%;}
}

#startScreen h1, p{
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #A5A5A5, 0 0 2px #A5A5A5, 0 0 3px #A5A5A5, 0 0 4px #A5A5A5, 0 0 5px #A5A5A5, 0 0 6px #A5A5A5, 0 0 7px #A5A5A5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body id="bodyGame" onload=startGame>
    <div id="startScreen">
      <div id="lineStart"></div>
      <div>
        <h1>press F11 to start</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>move with arrow keys <br>try to stay alive</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/start.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/game.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may gain a little insight from this video, it has collision detection as part of it. https://youtu.be/AaGK-fj-BAM - Build stake with html canvas and javascript

Comment: Yeah bad teacher, bad school, one of the worst IT studies according to a recent study. My whole class just copies games from the internet and edits them, I tried making one from scratch but without any information it's difficult, I might just start an online course after next week so I atleast learn something.

Comment: @Raphael we went to higher ups, every teacher and had multiple discussions with them, nothing has changed